# Return value by using procedurally generated variable identifier

Tags: c#, .net, razor, nancy

An example:

```
@foreach (var p in products)
{
    <a href="/@(p.Path)">@translations.@(p.TextId)</a>
}
```

The `@translations.@(p.textId)` does not work, but that is along the lines what I think of as the *procedurally generated variable identifier*.

I imagine, to return value that would correspond to, as if I'd have written: `@translations.helloworldproduct` or `@translations.otherproduct`.

And in my `translations` database, I'd have: `helloworldproduct = "Hello, World!"` and `otherproduct = "Yet another product test."`.

The HTML result would be:

```html
<a href="/products/1">Hello, World!</a>
<a href="/products/2">Yet another product test.</a>
```

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: Are you using Web Pages or MVC?

Comment: I'm using Razor with NancyFX, might say, as a standalone library. Added [tag:nancy] tag to Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work because you're essentially trying to pull the equivalent of a JS `eval`. Well ok, you can get it to work, but you'd have to use reflection and it's both ugly and slow.

You'd be much better off giving `translations` an indexer, such as the one provided for free with the generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. (Note I'm not sure what type `translations` is. I'm assuming it's either an anonymous type or some concrete class with properties.) Then you could use the indexer:

```
@translations[p.TextId]
```

Comment: I see. Yeah, already thought that it's either impossible or hacky, am tackling the path of indexer already.